# NVIDIA DVI problems

Tags: nvidia, dvi

I just bought a 3rd monitor, plugged it into the DVI output of my NVIDIA graphics card (the other 2 monitors take the VGA and HDMI outputs) and ran into problems. The monitor is fine using VGA or HDMI.

I'm using a VGA lead through a DVI converter. The graphics card is:
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti] (rev a2)

I'm using the latest nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 16.04.

The problem is that all the screens keep going blank, then coming back to life. It seems the machine can't decide the resolution of the DVI connected monitor, keeps changing it and (maybe) restarting the X server.

I've followed advice in other threads and tried saving the edid file and telling xorg.conf about it, but the problem remains.

I'd be grateful of any advice.

Update: I just found the Xorg log file is full of repetitions of the following.

```
[  1226.216] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2367 (DFP-0): connected
[  1226.216] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2367 (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
[  1226.216] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2367 (DFP-0): 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
```

Answer (score 1):

I appear to have solved it, but I think it's a bug in Settings -> Screen Display, or whatever lives underneath that.

In /var/log/Xorg.0.log I figured out that the VGA output gets called "CRT-0", the HDMI output gets called "DFP-2" and the DVI outputs are "DFP-0" and "DFP-1".

It seems that something somewhere is determined that, in a horizontal arrangement, CRT-0 (VGA) has to be the leftmost screen and DFP-2 (HDMI) has to be the rightmost screen.

If you have some other arrangement and then use Settings -> Screen Display to rearrange the panels, it breaks.

I added the following to /etc/X11/xorg.conf under Section "Screen", but am not sure it's required.

```
Option "ConnectedMonitor" "CRT-0, DVI-0, DVI-2"
```

I hope this saves someone some time.

**Update 2017-08-16**:
Having made various changes to my system this problem reocurred. I faffed around for ages, before finding that the solution here is the only solution. Adding

```
Option "ConnectedMonitor" "CRT-0, DFP-0, DFP-1"
```

to /etc/X11/xorg.conf solved the problem (**note** DFP-0 and 1, **not** DVI). The DFP-0, 1 and 2 appear to depend on which outputs I've got monitors plugged into.

I've no idea why, and I've no idea why no one else on the whole of the Web is having this issue.

Comment: Please click the gray check mark beside your answer to change its color to green and mark your answer as accepted.